# Why is my web page not observing the max-width and min-width rules?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having an issue with my web page of my resume not adhering to my min-width and max-width rules in css. I'm not really sure why. My page looks great with great margins on either side below a width of 1200px, but when the width goes higher than this the whole page content starts to list over to the right side and move off of the screen. I'm trying to make the entire body have a max width of something like 992px because a resume works better when viewed at about the width of a piece of paper on the screen. However, the layout looks awful when at full size.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Resume - Tyler Cheek</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container header">
            <h1>Tyler Cheek</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="contact-left col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <p>(919)-397-8116</p>
                        <p>Github: <a href="https://github.com/Hoid" target="_blank">github.com/Hoid</a></p>
                        <p>tylerlcheek@gmail.com</p>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-right col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <p>2604 Hillsborough Street Apt. 202</p>
                    <p>Raleigh, NC 27607</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
                <h5><b>Summary</b></h5>
            <p>&emsp;&emsp;Team player software engineer with open-source, frontend, backend, and management experience. I make others around me better through excellent communication and a purely constructive attitude. You should hire me because I have a passion for making cool stuff that makes people’s lives better and the broad technical aptitude to do it.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <h5><b>Objective</b></h5>
            <p>&emsp;&emsp;Seeking a full-time position in Software Development for an innovative company that will help me specialize my skills. I have a vast foundation that allows me to learn new things quickly and want experiences that will help me deepen my skillset.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="overflow: auto;">
            <h5><b>Education</b></h5>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="education-left col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <p>&emsp;&emsp;NC State University, Raleigh NC</p>
                    <p>&emsp;&emsp;B.S., Computer Engineering May 2017</p>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="container professional-experience">
            <h5><b>Professional Experience</b></h5>
            <div>
                <div style="overflow: auto;">
                    <div class="position">
                        <p><u>QA Lead</u></p>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="company-dates">
                        <p>Imaginovation</p>
                        <p>December 2017 – April 2018</p>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <ul class="position-information">
                    <li>Led a team of 3 offshore and 1 local Test Engineers in Quality Control, the Software Test Life Cycle, Automation best practices, Team Communication, and Time Management</li>
                    <li>Introduced and Documented a new effort in website test automation using Snaptest</li>
                    <li>Initiated a system of code reviews and a deployment plan throughout the company</li>
                    <li>Developed 10 automated test scripts for API endpoints in Go and numerous others in Postman using Javascript</li>
                    <li>Created over 75 automated tests for websites across various projects in Snaptest</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div style="overflow: auto;">
                    <div class="position">
                        <p><u>Developer/Project Manager</u></p>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="company-dates">
                        <p>Imaginovation</p>
                        <p>April 2017 – December 2017</p>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <ul class="position-information">
                    <li>Developed a base API framework and production-ready endpoints in Go</li>
                    <li>Designed the Bluetooth LE communication scheme for a mobile application to a custom proprietary IOT healthcare product in C</li>
                    <li>Led 3 teams of developers across 3 projects in multiple platforms, 2 of which were from start to completion</li>
                    <li>Created a Unity demo project with lightsabers for the Meta 2 Augmented Reality headset</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div style="overflow: auto;">
                    <div class="position">
                        <p><u>Software Development Student</u></p>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="company-dates">
                        <p>Blackberry</p>
                        <p>Aug. – Dec. 2015</p>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <ul class="position-information">
                    <li>Delivered solutions for 14 software defects and 2 user stories using Java on Android</li>
                    <li>Contributed to team-wide software integrity using a peer code review process in Gerrit</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div style="overflow: auto;">
                    <div class="position">
                        <p><u>Software Test Student</u></p>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="company-dates">
                        <p>Blackberry</p>
                        <p>Aug. – Dec. 2014, May – Aug. 2016</p>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <ul class="position-information">
                    <li>Documented 51 unique software issues in a Scrum development cycle</li>
                    <li>Scripted automated test suites for several user stories in RIDE, spanning hundreds of test cases</li>
                    <li>Developed an Excel macro that parses thousands of user reviews for keywords and trends</li>
                    <li>Seamlessly Transitioned between 3 mobile operating systems and 2 separate applications</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container various-technical-experience">
                <h5><b>Various Other Technical Experience</b></h5>
            <ul class="position-information">
                <li><b>Golang/Open Source:</b> Contributed to the alexa-skills-git-golang and go-jira Github open-source repos</li>
                <li><b>XHTML/CSS:</b> Built a version of this resume using XHTML/CSS</li>
                <li><b>PHP:</b> Personal websitethat interfaces with the OMDB movie search API</li>
                <li><b>Python:</b> Personal desktop app client using PyQT4, UI creation, API utilization, Multithreading</li>
                <li><b>C:</b> Compiler design, Text autocomplete function, GPS application</li>
                <li><b>C++:</b> Team project working with a LIDAR sensor to detect and analyze objects for an autonomous vehicle – used OpenCV and Visual Studio</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
/*
body {
    max-width: 992px;
}
*/

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.position {
    float: left;
    line-height: 0.8em;
}

.company-dates {
    float: right;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-align: right;
}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media (min-width : 320px) {
    body {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        min-width: 320px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    }
    .contact-right {
        text-align: left;
    }
}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media (min-width : 480px) {
    body {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media (min-width : 768px) {
    body {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .contact-right {
        text-align: right;
    }
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media (min-width : 992px) {
    body {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        max-width: 992px;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media (min-width : 1200px) {
    body {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the grid.less CSS file (imported by the bootstrap CSS file) on line 30 you have this:

```
 .container {
     width: 1170px;
 }
```

Set its `width: auto` in a (the?) style block in the head, thereby overruling the grid.less file, and the problem should be solved.

Comment: And @Tyler avoid using width specified in px. Just width not min, max width

Comment: How do I set the width to auto in the style block in the head? Do I just do `<head style="width: auto;"> ?

Comment: @Frank Conjin I looked up what you meant by style block and created a block that looks like this: `<style>width: auto;</style> in the head, but that had no effect.

Comment: @TylerCheek -- That's why I wrote that you have set *its* `width:auto`. So the code should be: `<style>.container {width: auto !important;}</style>`. (I added the `!important` just to make sure it will last.)

Comment: @FrankConijn Unfortunately there's no change. I have `<style>.container {width: auto !important;}</style>` in my `<head>` underneath the bootstrap file link but no luck.

Comment: @TylerCheek -- That's strange, because in my set-up that cured. Do you have it online? Modern browsers have some awesome tools with which we can test, and the live version is always the best test environment.

Comment: I can't seem to get my Godaddy account login to play nicely, so I can't get it up online currently. I'm using Brackets to see a Live preview of the page. I've also tried to view it just using the standard opening the xhtml page in the browser as a file, no change there.

Comment: @TylerCheek -- Just let me know through a new comment when you have it online.